# Why does base class pointer always point to base class even if it holds a derived class object address?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have gone through some of the previous posts on the same issue but I couldn't find any satisfying answer.
Why does the base class pointer always point to the base class even if it holds the address of a derived class's object? I know that, because of this reason, the `virtual` keyword came into the picture, but I couldn't figure out why the base class pointer always points to the base class even if it hold the address of a derived class. Could anyone explain it ?

```
class base
{
  public:void fn()
  {
    cout << "I am in base" << endl;
  }
};

class derived : public base
{
  public:void fn()
  {
    cout << "I am in derived"<< endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  base *p;     // creating pointer object for base class
  derived obj; // creating object for derived class
  p=&obj;      // storing object of derived class in pointer
  p->fn();     // If pointer has address of derived class object
               // then why still it print base class function
               // why we need to use virtual keyword to print
               // derived class function?
}
```

Comment: If you already know what `virtual` does, and where and why you need it, what is the question?

Comment: You've declared `p` as a pointer to `base`, so that's how the compiler will interpret it. If you want a pointer to `derived`, you have to declare it as such. If you know (or suspect) `p` points to a `derived` and want to treat it that way, use `dynamic_cast` to get a `derived*`.

Comment: @k-ballo my  question is why base class pointer always point to base class even it hold address of derived class,why o/p it I am in base why not o/p is i am in derived?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object of a derived class always contains an object of base class type somewhere inside it. This is called a "base class subobject". If `p` has type `base*`, then when `p` is set to point to an object of type `derived`, it is actually set to point to the `base` subobject of that `derived` object.

This behaviour ensures that base class non-static member functions can be called from pointers even when they actually point to an object of the derived class. Because of this, the implementation doesn't *have* to look up, at runtime, whether `p` points to a complete `base` object or a complete `derived` object; no matter what, it's still pointing to a `base` object (which might simply happen to be a base class subobject).

In order to ensure that the derived class's implementation of the function is called even though you used a pointer to base class, the compiler has to generate additional code to *look up*, at runtime, whether the pointer points to a complete `base` object or a complete `derived` object. If you want to force it to do this, you mark the function `virtual`. If not, then C++ does not force you to pay the cost for virtual calls when you don't need them.

Comment: thanks again i encounter another problem this time i made pointer for derived class which hold address of base object .now using derived class pointer i am unable to print base function why?

Comment: @user3784175: That is due to how lookup works. When you call `fn()` on a pointer/reference/value of type `derived` lookup starts at the `derived` level, it finds `fn` and stops there calling this function. The function `derived::fn` *hides* `base::fn`, they are not overrides, but the base one will be hidden by the derived. You can still call the base function by casting to base pointer/ref or by qualifying the function call: `derived d; d.base::fn();`

Answer (score 0):

> why base class pointer always point to base class even it hold derived class object address?

The reason is that compiler ignores the *contents of* the pointer `p` and chooses the member function (if not declared `virtual`) that matches the *type of* the pointer.

Comment: ya but my question is why it ignore the contents of the pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not make `fn` virtual. Since `p` points to a `base` the method for base is called. If you want to have the other behaviour, declare `fn` in base as virtual.

When setting `p`, the compiler cannot know that p points to a `derived`. In this trivial case it could, but in other cases, for example when calling a function accepting a pointer to a base object, it cannot:

Consider the simple function

```
void doStuff(Base* base)
    {
    base->fn();
    }
```

When compiling `doStuff`, the compiler cannot know that base originally pointed to a `derived` object. So to be consistent, it is best to not use the fact that the type is known in the trivial case given.

To keep track of what "kind of" `base` a pointer points to, one declares the considered function as *virtual*. This typically adds an invisible pointer to all classes that derives from `base`. This pointer points a the *vtable* which in turn contains pointers to all *virtual methods*.

Why isn't the methods virtual by default? Because it adds an invisible member, that

- Takes some space
- Will break an ABI specified with POD:s
- Sometimes it makes sense to dump a plain struct to disk. But pointers should not be written to disk.